# Associativity of Addition Modulo $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the following a valid proof for showing that addition modulo $2\ +_2$ is associative on $\mathbb{Z}_{2} = \left\{0, 1\right\}$? Here, $\left(\star\right)$ refers to the fact that I have made use of the property of associativity of $+$ on $\mathbb{Z}$.
$$
\begin{align}
\left(a+_2 b\right) +_2 c &= \left(\left(a+b\right)\operatorname{mod}\left(2\right) + c\right)\operatorname{mod}(2) \\
&= \left(a+b\right)\operatorname{mod}\left(2\right)\operatorname{mod}\left(2\right)+c\operatorname{mod}\left(2\right) \\
&=\left(a+b\right)\operatorname{mod}\left(2\right)+c\operatorname{mod}\left(2\right) \\
&= \left(\left(a+b\right)+c\right)\operatorname{mod}\left(2\right) \\
&\stackrel{\left(\star\right)\label{s}}= \left(a+\left(b+c\right)\right)\operatorname{mod}\left(2\right) \\
&= a +_2 \left(b +_2 c\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This is unclear. $\mathbb{Z}_2$ has two elements and you can check associativity in just a few cases if that's what you are asking. If you are asking something about arithmetic in the integers, you have to start with your definition of $+_2$ when the things you are adding are integers. (Do not try to clarify in comments. [edit] the question.

Comment: After the first line, "$((a+b)\bmod(2) + c)\bmod (2)$" is not always equal to "$(a+b)\bmod (2) \bmod (2) + c\bmod (2)$", even for $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z_2$. For counter example, $a+b=1$ and $c=1$.